# EXCEL UDF converting a formula to value after computation

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I hope I am wording this right, I am very new to VBA so my wording might be off.

I have this very basic UDF script to create a timestamp when a value is entered in a referenced cell:

```
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)

If Reference.Value <> "" Then

Timestamp = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")

Else

Timestamp = ""

End If

End Function
```

Now the problem I am running into is that when I close and reopen my excel sheet, the timestamps generated all get updated to the current time... not good.I could of course manually convert to value after the timestamp is generated, but that kinda defeats the purpose of automating it all.

My question is, is there something I could add to my code to transform the generated timestamp from formula to value, when the if conditional is met?

can anyone help, or is there a better way to acheive this? thanks!

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_Change` event (or maybe `Worksheet_Calculate` depending on your setup) and write the timestamp as a *value*.

Comment: UDF are live like formula and will change whenever they recalculate.